# Microsoft Custom translator training through python code

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am trying to train custom translator for English-Spanish language pair.

I am able to do that from `Azure` portal but I want to integrate training in my `Python code` in which I can provide `training`, `testing` and `tuning` set and starts training.

I was going through its document but unable to find anything.

Is there any way to do that and if there is how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have just added some sample code demonstrating how to handle some of the common Custom Translator tasks through the API.  The sample code can be found here with detailed instructions.

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/CustomTranslatorApiSamples